# Digital Persona Windows SDK problems!

Tags: c#, windows, sdk

I am trying integrate DP controls into our application and  I have noticed few issues in the SDK and I hope somebody out there will be able to help me out.

1. When the application is not focused, it's not triggering the `OnFingerTouch` event or any other event.
2. I found it very slow when I tried to use 3000 fingerprints. I have to validate each fingerprint using `Verificator.Verify()` (even when all the 3000 were loaded using a `HashTable`)

Please help me to solve these problems.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Need to set the priority

   In the Capture class has  `Priority` set it to `Low`
2. have to purchase their SDK :|

Comment: Could you please elaborate on #1?  What do you mean by "need to set the priority"? I am having a similar problem - I want touch events to "wake" the application.